# Error certificates generate by Digicert on Nginx

Tags: nginx, ssl

I add a domain name and some subdomain buy with 1&1 and my web server is on debian with NGinx.

I begin to configure a website with a subdomain. Without the SSL, it works but now, I try to add the SSL. I generated it via the 1&1 interface which use Digicert and I follow these instructions: https://knowledge.digicert.com/solution/SO17664.html

So, after the certificate bundle, I configure my nginx file for my subdomain to use the SSL:

```
server {
            listen 443 ssl;
            listen [::]:443 ssl;
            keepalive_timeout   70;

            ssl on;
            ssl_certificate    /etc/ssl/certs/_.my_domain.ca_ssl_certificate_complete.pem;
            ssl_certificate_key    /etc/ssl/certs/_.my_domain.ca_private_key.key;

            server_name    subdomain.mydomain.ca;
            root           /var/www/Mysoft;
            index          index.php;

            location / {
               try_files $uri /index.php;
               fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
               include fastcgi.conf;
            }

    }
```

Nginx log:

```
Mar 09 23:35:03 vps97652.vps.ovh.ca nginx[15092]: nginx: [emerg] SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file("/etc/ssl/certs/_.my_domain.ca_private_key.key") failed (SSL: error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch)
Mar 09 23:35:03 vps97652.vps.ovh.ca nginx[15092]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Mar 09 23:35:03 vps97652.vps.ovh.ca systemd[1]: nginx.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Mar 09 23:35:03 vps97652.vps.ovh.ca systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

I  don't know if a configuration is missing or if the problem come from the fact my certificate and my intermediate certificate have the extension .cer instead of .crt  When I done my research for my error, I find .cer files seem be equivalent to .crt (just a different extension). I tried to inverse certificate and intermediate certificate in the bundle without success, use only the certificate with the intermediate certificate, same problem.

Like I have never configure a certificate before, I'm a little bit lost.

Thank you.

Comment: The error says: "key values mismatch". You need to use the same private key that goes with the certificate. You can't use a different private key.

Comment: It's the same, reason I don't understand :( I will try to regenerate my certificate, write to the support of Digicert if it doesn't work :-/